# Javascript Q library browser support

Tags: javascript, q, browser-support

We are looking to use the [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) library in one of our project on the client side. But we want to make sure that the library is supported by the browser we need to support. We weren't able to find a authoritative source that would  provide that information.

Is it safe to say that the library support IE 9 and above since it is used in AngularJS and that the framework supports IE9 and above ([source](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie)).

Comment: `Q` is not used in AngularJS! Angular uses their own library `$q`, which was inspired by (and named after) `Q`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

From: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

> This is an implementation of promises/deferred objects inspired by
>   Kris Kowal's Q.

They are not the same library.

That being said, test the Q library in a given browser at the [link](https://rawgit.com/kriskowal/q/v1/spec/q-spec.html) at the bottom of it's [github page](https://github.com/kriskowal/q):

https://rawgit.com/kriskowal/q/v1/spec/q-spec.html

Comment: IE10 & IE11 fails one test. Does it imply that it cannot be used?

Comment: How many does Chrome fail? This is a third-party, open source library (just like jQuery/Angular/Ember/etc). Use it at your own risk (just like you use those other libraries at your own risk).

Comment: Failed a bunch for me on my PC (mainly due to timeouts). Chrome on Mac is working fine. **EDIT** looks like the test spec has just been updated as Chrome on PC is no longer failing the tests that were failing just moments ago.